# how to create a file from a byte array

Tags: database, file, compression, arrays

in my database I stored a byte array, and when I look at it, it looks like this:

> 0x255044462D312E330D0A312030206F626A0D0A5B2F504446202F54657874202F496D61676542202F496D61676543202F496D616765495D0D0A656E646F626A0D0A352030206F626A0D0A3C3C202F4C656E6774682031363534202F46696C746572202F466C6174654465636F6465203E3E2073747265616D200D0A5809A559CD8E1C3510BE47CA3BF89820E1D82EFFA2550E08160E40FE4670401C26999D28B09B250B8477C9DBF12654B9ED6A77BB7B6627A368D23BD5E5AACF5F7D6D577B1E3EF8209C973E810841E55D0A143870E1D3A3AC551A8073A7EADE81
>   ...

Is there any easy way how t ocreate a file (pdf in this case)? 
Possibly not using any programming language ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure this is pdf data, you can just paste it into empty file and change extension to .pdf.